# How to pass a function into a map of another object

Tags: javascript, dictionary, reactjs

I'm trying to create a table with a row for each object in an array, but I also want each row to contain a Button with a custom onClick function that is inherited from the row creator:

```
var React = require('react');
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
...

export class ObjectTable extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          ...
          <tbody>
            {
              this.props.objects.map(
                function(object) {
                  return <TableRowWrapper key={object.id} object={object} action={this.props.action} />;
                  }
                )
            }
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    )
  }
};

var TableRowWrapper = React.createClass({
  ...
  render() {
    return (
      <tr>
        <td><Button onClick={this.props.action}>Object 1</Button></td>
      </tr>
    )
  }
});
```

Both `objects` and `action` are passed to `<ObjectTable />` as props, and in any other element within the `ObjectTable` class I'd be able to call `{this.props.action}` to get it.

However, it doesn't work when I try to call from within the `objects` map (presumably because `this` no longer refers to `ObjectTable`). I've read the examples in [map Method (Array) (JavaScript)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff679976(v=VS.94).aspx), but I can't do `this.props.objects.map(function(object, this) {...`, or any other permutation of `this.props`, `this.props.action`, etc. either.

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: There was a typo: `<TableRowWrapper>` should be `<TableRowWrapper`. Have you got it in your code too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store a reference to the original **this** and use it in the map callback function:

```
export class ObjectTable extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var self = this;
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          ...
          <tbody>
            {
              this.props.objects.map(
                function(obj) {
                  return <TableRowWrapper key={obj.id} object={obj} action={self.props.action} />;
                  }
                )
            }
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    )
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use arrow functions

```
export class ObjectTable extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          ...
          <tbody>
            {
              this.props.objects.map(
                (object) => {
                  return <TableRowWrapper key={object.id} object={object} action={this.props.action} />;
                  }
                )
            }
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    )
  }
};
```

Comment: please check again forgot to add =>

Comment: this,props.actions, this would point to the react class instance not the prop.objects map one